# Pimcore event for publishing a version

Tags: events, extjs, overriding, pimcore

Do we have any event for publishing a previous version in pimcore 3?
In plugin I can override it using extjs startup.js with below code

```
 pimcoreReady: function (params, broker) {
    Ext.override(pimcore.object.versions, {
        publishVersion: function (index, grid) {
            //code goes here
        }
    });
 }
```

But I want to override publish version for different classes in different plugins. But if I do so only one override works as expected.
Can I put class based conditions like if my class is abc only then override  like

```
if(class == 'abc'){
 Ext.override(pimcore.object.versions, {
            publishVersion: function (index, grid) {
                //code goes here
             }
      });
 }
```

or any other suggestion to overcome this.

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.